# Повторить символы в cтроке

Tags: c#, строки, символы, повторы

Есть символ. Любой. Например: $
Как можно повторить его в строке определенное количество раз или исходя из определенных условий задачи?
Например, сделать строку из символов больше количество букв слова на два символа:

стол
$$$$$$

Comment: `s=new String('$', 6);` 14 секунд в Гугле

Comment: Спасибо. Этот ответ видел. Не подходит. Количество символов не известно первоначально по условиям задачи. Известно только число букв в слове. И вот, зная число букв, надо делать строку из символов разной длины. В данном случае, известно только количество букв (4). Должно выйти 6 символов. Т.е. как прописать прибавление еще 2-х?

Comment: _как прописать прибавление еще 2-х_ - Э? Детишки в первом классе осваивают операцию сложения. Знак `+`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
String s1 = "qwer";
String s2 = new String('$', 2 + s1.Length); 
Console.WriteLine(s2);

s1 += new String('$', 6 - s1.Length);
Console.WriteLine(s1);
```

Answer (score 5):

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const int VALUE = 2;
            string[] results =
            {
                Repeat('$', "тестируем".Length, VALUE),
                Repeat('-', "на".Length, VALUE),
                Repeat('=', "нескольких".Length, VALUE),
                Repeat('*', "словах".Length, VALUE)
            };

            foreach (string result in results)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(result);
            }
        }

        private static string Repeat(char ch, int count, int summand)
        {
            return new string(ch, count + summand);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Наверное стоит добавить  деталей в ответ. Например, что мы тестируем и какой результат на вызоде имеем?

Comment: @tym32167, не понял какие детали нужно добавить. Автор вопроса задал вопрос весьма неконкретно, я написал ответ как понял. Я как вижу, ответ выше выбрали, там вообще никаких подробностей нет. Видимо, это не проблема. Результат мы имеет такой, какой просил автор.

Comment: Ну а результат то вашего кода какой? Я, например, сходу не понял что код вообще делает. В тексте кода вы что то тестируете, но результатов теста нет.

Comment: Ну так видно же, что я не тестами покрыл метод, а просто написал приложение, которое автор мог у себя запустить и увидеть результат, который он просил. Вы считаете, что здесь это реально нужно? Наверное, нужно убрать текст "тестируем на нескольких словах". Код берёт длину слова, прибавляет к ней значение и выводит символ столько раз, сколько получилось после сложения.

Comment: @tym32167, сама задача какая-то мутная. Здесь, если подумать, вообще метод не нужен. Это настолько простая задача, что я даже не понял, точно ли требуется написать хотя бы один метод. И точно ли я правильно понимаю проблему, так как это вопрос уровня "я пошёл в детский сад и учусь читать" и кажется, что такое даже спросить не могли.

Comment: Вы пишете очевидные вещи - да, видно, что тестов у вас нет хотя есть текст про тестирование. Вопрос сам по себе может быть каким угодно непонятным, это в данный момент не делает ваш ответ лучше или хуже. Мои слова также не претензия к вашему ответу, а совет по его улучшению - вы же понимаете, что сам я могу и в вашем коде разобраться и запустить его, и через 30 секунд после чтения вашего кода я его понял полностью.

Comment: Я обычно не пишку даже такие комментарии под вопросами, что мне не нравятся, но я помню вас и ваши ответы и помню, что вы молоды и ещё учитесь, потому подумал, что подсказка писать более качественные ответы вам может помочь. Помочь не только здесь на сайте, но и вообще в профессии - это хорошо иметь привычку писать код и сразу показывать его корректность. Я, например, стараюсь [делать также](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A179763+%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4), может не всегда это соблюдаю, но вцелом это помогает деражать какую-никакую планку качества ответа.

Comment: Я не призываю вас со мной спорить, вы можете меня просто проигнорировать, в этом нет ничего плохого или хорошего - скажем так, я вам дал совет, а вы делаете с этим что хотите :)

Answer (score 4):

Мне предыдущие ответы нравятся, я просто для коллекции оставлю linq-версию:

```
private static string Repeater(string source, char placeholder, int additional)
{
    return new string(Enumerable.Repeat(placeholder, source.Length + additional).ToArray());
}
```

Интересно кстати, что будет лучше преобразовывать в строку `new string` или `string.Concat` (нет под рукой студии):

```
private static string Repeater(string source, char placeholder, int additional)
{
    return string.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(placeholder, source.Length + additional));
}
```

Ну и вот ещё linq-вариант, на других функциях:

```
private static string Repeater(string source, char placeholder, int additional)
{
    var a = source.Select(x => placeholder);
    var b = Enumerable.Repeat(placeholder, additional);
    return new string(a.Concat(b).ToArray());
}
```

(не стал в однострочник соединять для наглядности)

Ну и ещё один в голову пришёл:

```
private static string Repeater(string source, char placeholder, int additional)
{
    return Enumerable.Repeat(placeholder, source.Length + additional)
                     .Aggregate(new StringBuilder(), (seed, c) => seed.Append(c))
                     .ToString();
}
```